# jQuery Countdown not starting, working only after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Countdown plugin [here](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

I've a page with a play button, when I click on it to display a div (previously hidden) with the countdown.

It work fine on localhost, but when I upload the script on the web server the countdown starts only when I refresh the page.

Here's the code:

```
[...]
$("#projectInProgress").show(0, '', function () {
    $("#countUp").countdown('destroy');
    $("#countUp").countdown({
        since: moment(startDateAtt.replace('T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toDate(),
        compact: true,
        format: 'HMS',
        description: ''
    });
});
[...]
```

I've tried to put the countdown creation on the `.show()` function callback, but it did not work.

I've also tried with this code:

```
[...]
$("#projectInProgress").show();
$("#countUp").countdown('destroy');
$("#countUp").countdown({
    since: moment(startDateAtt.replace('T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toDate(),
    compact: true,
    format: 'HMS',
    description: ''
});
});
[...]
```

Each code block is inside a function and it's called inside a `$( document ).ready()` block in the page.

`#countUp` is the id of the countdown

`#projectInProgress` is the id of the div that contains the countdown

Any suggestion?

Comment: Seems like you are not using the show function correctly, did you tried without it. You can use it in document.ready function

Comment: Or `window.onload` function

Comment: I've updated the description of my problem. My countdown code is inside a function that is called from a $( document ).ready() block.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to reproduce the problem ?